# Best Amazon RDS Engine For ASP.NET Core 3.1 Project Using Entity Framework

Tags: amazon-web-services, asp.net-core, amazon-rds

I'm new to AWS deployment and as i stated in the title I'm publishing an ASP.NET Core 3.1 (Code First). I stopped at the selection of Amazon RDS engine (Aurora, SQL Server, MariaDB etc.). I don't know what is the best decision for my case and I'd like anyone with experience to briefly explain the differences between them and any important aspects i should know about this subject.
Any information is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For these three database management systems, they are all relational DBMS which is suitable for ASP.NET Core 3.1 Project using Entity Framework. These aspects below is key to choose in my opinion.

[image]

MySQL  - **Free**
MS SQL Server  - **Popular**
Amazon Aurora  - **High performance**

As for me, I suggest `Microsoft SQL Server`.
Popularity means more community support and examples which help u quick start.

The chart below is trend of **Amazon Aurora** vs. **MariaDB** vs. **Microsoft SQL Server** Popularity from DB-Engines Ranking.

[image]

Below is [DB-Engines](https://db-engines.com/en/ranking) top 10 of DBMS according to their popularity.

March 2021
[image]

More differences of Amazon Aurora vs. MariaDB vs. Microsoft SQL Server
[image]